# Custom login flow with Python Social Auth for passwordless login

Tags: django, django-authentication, python-social-auth

For a Django project I am working on, beside the social authentication methods provided by python social auth, I am trying to implement and integrate also a [passwordless authentication](http://passwordless.org) flow. Beside other advantages, the most appealing part of this approach to me is that, it unifies sign-up and sign-in, just like in other social authentication backends. This provides unification of email authentication

Each time a user wants to login (or sign-up) they only submit their email, receive the temporary login token via email, click on it, and they are in. A long lasting session is initiated so they don't need to do it frequently.

I am using a custom EMAIL_VALIDATION_FUNCTION to send the email, as stated in the docs and it sends the token fine. My pipeline looks like this:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.mail.mail_validation',
    'barrio.profiles.pipeline.authenticate_email',  # custom method to authenticate email
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_by_email',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
)
```

When the authentication link is clicked (i.e. /complete/email/?validation_code=) the pipeline resumes from the 'social.pipeline.mail.mail_validation' and it exists the pipeline with authentication failure and the execution never reaches my custom authentication function.

Even if it did so, it is not clear to me how I would have access to the validation result and check if it is OK.

Instead of trying to do this on the pipeline, should I do it with a custom view and instead of directing the user to '/email/complete/' view, direct them to my view and authenticate?

Python social auth is great for its flexibility but the tradeoff is the complexity. Sometimes I feel lost. Thanks for an help.

Comment: @omab, the developer of python social auth very kindly added an example of how to implement this: https://github.com/omab/psa-passwordless